# DO android_alarm_manager Work on IOS or it only support android?

Tags: ios, flutter, alarmmanager

I am working on flutter App where I use **android alarm manager** to send notification  at particular time duration, once alarm triggers. This work properly in android but not in IOS. Is there any possibility to use  Android Alarm Manager in IOS or is there any another way to send notification at particular time duration in IOS.

Comment: `AlarmManager` ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager ) is solely an Android class. Do you mean `android_alarm_manager` plugin ( https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager ) ?

Answer (score 1):

[`android_alarm_manager`](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) is just a Flutter wrapper over Android's intrinsic [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) - works only for Android and does not provide any iOS mirror (like `shared_preferences` plugin does via using `NSUserDefaults` for iOS and `SharedPreferences` for Android). [You can check it out](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/android_alarm_manager/ios/Classes/AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin.m#L18) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is **NO** possibility to use Android Alarm Manager in iOS. I suggest you to check out the Firebase Push Notification Service if needed.